# How do you create a pan and zoom gesture using two fingers in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making a drawing application as a feature of a bigger app. One of its implementation is to use a two-finger gesture system for panning and zooming on the canvas. I can't use single-finger gestures because they are mainly used for drawing. I've heard of [MultiDragGestureRecognizer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/MultiDragGestureRecognizer-class.html) but I'm struggling with its implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **InteractiveViewer** widget to create two-finger gesture system for panning and zooming on the canvas. It's super simple, just wrap your widget with **InteractiveViewer**.
Here is a code example:

```
                 InteractiveViewer(
                    child: CachedNetworkImage(
                      imageUrl: imgUrl,
                      imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                          image: DecorationImage(
                              image: imageProvider, fit: BoxFit.contain),
                        ),
                      ),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      placeholder: (context, url) => Container(
                          height: ProjectResource.screenHeight * .3,
                          child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())),
                      errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Container(
                          height: ProjectResource.screenHeight * .3,
                          child: Center(child: Icon(Icons.error))),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: I did implement an InteractiveViewer widget to the whole canvas to control its maxScale and minScale. I was thinking that would implement the two-finger gesture feature; however, the InteractiveViewer's child is a GestureDetector whose child is a Container that fills up the whole screen. The GestureDetector is primarily responsible for drawing on the canvas. Since the whole screen is under the influence of GestureDetector, any gestures would be registered under GestureDetector first and not the InteractiveViewer.

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same task:

1. Draw/mark cells (one pointer / finger);
2. Decrease / increase the size of the area where I mark (two pointers / fingers) and move the area in any direction (one pointer / finger).

I did this by creating two modes that the user switches between:

1. Mark mode (for example - <TextButton -> onPress> or <GestureDetector -> onTap>).
2. Motion and scale mode (GestureDetector -> onScale) - attached code diagram.

   ```
          child: GestureDetector(
              onScaleStart: (details) {
                ...
                setState(() {
                  ... 
                });
                ...
              },
              onScaleUpdate: (details) {
                ...
                setState(() {
                  ... 
                });
                ...
              },
              onScaleEnd: (details) {
                ...
                setState(() {
                  ...
                });
                ...
              },                  
              child: Container(
                ...               
              ),
            ),
   ```